# How do I tell my custom FragmentPagerAdapter to stop destroying my fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter, and my app has previously used just two fragments (different types) without issues.

I just added a third fragment, though, and now my adapter/viewpager seems to be destroying my fragments when I get far away from them. For example, if I'm on page 1, page 3 is destroyed and recreated when I get close to it. If I'm on page 3, the same happens to page 1.

This is causing lots of issues in my app. The fragments aren't very RAM-heavy at all, so how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Is it destroying the Fragment or destroying the View?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I check?

Comment: You just said "it's causing a lot of issues."  If the Fragment is being destroyed, then it's state is being wiped from memory and reseting to defaults when reloaded.

Comment: If you use `FragmentPagerAdapter` your `Fragments` once created will never be destroyed while swiping. Only onPause and onStop method will be called. Probably you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: And of course onDestroyView will be called too, after onStop.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).

In your case, the following should keep your fragments in memory and not destroy them.

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

However, I suspect that you are not correctly storing your view state when being destroyed. Your fragments should correctly handle being destroyed/recreated. Your fragments would for example also be destroyed and recreated if an orientation change happens. It could also happen if the user leaves your application and the system later needs memory and destroys your Activity. It should be able to reopen and be in the same state as before. If this is indeed the problem for you, consider saving state in [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). The saved state will be presented to you in [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) where you can initialize the state of the fragment to be the same as the destroyed one.

Comment: Perfect! This is going to be my temporary solution until I make my fragments more network-independent.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() is not called most of the times. E.g., you're on page 1, move to page 5: the first fragment goes through onDestroyView(), for example, but not onSaveInstanceState(). In my case at least.

Answer (score 5):

just override this method in FragmentpagerAdapter

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object);
}
```

remove `super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object);`

from your code

Comment: This will work as long as you _never_ want your Fragment destroyed (even if the FragmentPagerAdapter goes out of scope).  This could be problematic, but in some situations it's perfect.  For those problem situations, you could always call `destroyItem(..)` on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution :)