# save restore state listfragment with simpleadapter in viewpager

Tags: android-listfragment, simpleadapter

After a lot of searching, I can not find a solution to my problem.

The summary of my program I ve also checked with a tabhost.
It's viewpager viewpager has fragmentpageradapter who get an instance vector fragments, the fragments will identified by their position in the vector.
 The first fragment instantiates a listefragment using a simpleadapter.
The listfragment is loaded with json data oncreate.
In the GetView method of simpleadapter, I change a textview in one of the item using a button on the item and a textview which'm part of an instance of this fragmentactivity.

I have listfragment with different json given 4 different positions in my viewpager.
When I press the button on my item, my textview and change correct.

My problem 
When I turn pages in my viewpager and I return to the previous page of my viewpager, all calls to this issue 0
My question 
how to save and restore the state of the items in my listfragment?
Or do I make these?

My Attempts
Save and restore the fragment in my listfragment use a static method in the viewholder GetView of simpleadapter I'm turning around ............

Thanks 
in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research and have posted a question on this great forum.
I finally found my problem question.
Here is the solution

```
this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.tabviewpager2);
this.mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(this.mPagerAdapter.getCount());
```

Link stackoverflow
[Saving Fragment state in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834518/android-saving-fragment-state-in-viewpager)

link android
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29