# Saving the state of a viewpager using views as pages and not fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view, android-pageradapter

I have a viewpager that uses custom views and not fragments as pages.
this custom view is basically a linearlayout with an imageview since am using my viewpager to show images.

However when screen orientation changes, everything disappears. including my imageviews. i have done research and

- Most tutorials are showing how to do this with fragments.(in my case am not using fragments) [Android: Saving Fragment state in ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834518/saving-fragment-state-in-viewpager)

My viewpager adapter is using an arraylist which contain path to image files.

Below is my viewpager's adapter.(**NOTE:am using an arraylist where am adding items to it and then calling**`notifyDataSetChanged`)

Below is my viewpager's adapter class

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<ImagePaths> imagesArray;

public  ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ImagePaths> array, ){
    this.context = context;
    inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imagesArray = array;
}

public int getCount(){
    return imagesArray.size();
}

public boolean isViewFromObject(View view,Object object){
    return view == object;
}

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView);

    final String imagePath = imagesArray.get(position);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagePath, imageView);

    viewGroup.addView(view);
    return view;
}

public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
}
```

**What do i need to do to save the state of my viewpager?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to restore the state of my viewpager including it's current page when screen orientation changed by saving my arraylist and current position in

`onSaveInstanceState` method. later on i get the arraylist and position from the bundle in method `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompactActivity{

  private ArrayList<ImagePaths> listviewArray;
  private int savedImagePosition;

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        listviewArray = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("image_array");
        savedImagePosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("savedImagePosition");

    }else{
        listviewArray = new ArrayList<>();
        savedImagePosition =0;
    }

    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this,listviewArray);

    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(savedImagePosition,true);
  }

 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("image_array", listviewArray);
    outState.putInt("savedImagePosition",savedImagePosition);

}

}
```

**my viewpager adapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<ImagePaths> imagesArray;

public  ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ImagePaths> array, ){
    this.context = context;
    inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imagesArray = array;
}

public int getCount(){
    return imagesArray.size();
}

public boolean isViewFromObject(View view,Object object){
    return view == object;
}

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView);

    final String imagePath = imagesArray.get(position);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagePath, imageView);

    viewGroup.addView(view);
    return view;
}

public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
}
```